# Converting a dataframe to an array of struct of column names and values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a dataframe like this

```
val customer = Seq(
    ("C1", "Jackie Chan", 50, "Dayton", "M"),
    ("C2", "Harry Smith", 30, "Beavercreek", "M"),
    ("C3", "Ellen Smith", 28, "Beavercreek", "F"),
    ("C4", "John Chan", 26, "Dayton","M")
  ).toDF("cid","name","age","city","sex")
```

How can i get cid values in one column and get the rest of the values in an `array < struct < column_name, column_value > >` in spark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difficulty is that arrays must contain elements of the same type. Therefore, you need to cast all the columns to strings before putting them in an array (`age` is an int in your case). Here is how it goes:

```scala
val cols = customer.columns.tail
val result = customer.select('cid,
    array(cols.map(c => struct(lit(c) as "name", col(c) cast "string" as "value")) : _*) as "array")

result.show(false)

+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|cid|array                                                      |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|C1 |[[name,Jackie Chan], [age,50], [city,Dayton], [sex,M]]     |
|C2 |[[name,Harry Smith], [age,30], [city,Beavercreek], [sex,M]]|
|C3 |[[name,Ellen Smith], [age,28], [city,Beavercreek], [sex,F]]|
|C4 |[[name,John Chan], [age,26], [city,Dayton], [sex,M]]       |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+

result.printSchema()

root
 |-- cid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- array: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks @Oli, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using array and struct functions:

`customer.select($"cid", array(struct(lit("name") as "column_name", $"name" as "column_value"), struct(lit("age") as "column_name", $"age" as "column_value") ))`

will make:

```
 |-- cid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- array(named_struct(column_name, name AS `column_name`, NamePlaceholder(), name AS `column_value`), named_struct(column_name, age AS `column_name`, NamePlaceholder(), age AS `column_value`)): array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- column_name: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- column_value: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Map columns might be a better way to deal with the overall problem. You can keep different value types in the same map, without having to cast it to string.

```
df.select('cid',
    create_map(lit("name"), col("name"), lit("age"), col("age"),
               lit("city"), col("city"), lit("sex"),col("sex")
               ).alias('map_col')
  )
```

or wrap the map col in an array if you want it

This way you can still do numerical or string transformations on the relevant key or value. For example:

```
df.select('cid',
    create_map(lit("name"), col("name"), lit("age"), col("age"),
               lit("city"), col("city"), lit("sex"),col("sex")
               ).alias('map_col')
  )
df.select('*', 
      map_concat( col('cid'), create_map(lit('u_age'),when(col('map_col')['age'] < 18, True)))
)
```

Hope that makes sense, typed this straight in here so forgive if there's a bracket missing somewhere